# Changing the Fork() system call

Tags: c, linux, fork, system-calls

Hi I am trying create a system call that will count the number of forks that were called. I was going to change the fork system call so that it has a counter that will keep track of the number of times fork() was invoked. I was planning on adding a static variable to fork.h and then increment that everytime fork.c is called. I just don't understand what is going on in fork.c at all. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: Do you want to do this system-wide, or just inside of your own program?

Comment: I want to count all of the forks of all the processes in my system.

Comment: Can't you just start a process and query its pid?  Since the system starts up with only one process running, whatever the pid of your program is is the number of times fork was called, right?

Comment: @Carl Norum: Not even close.  pids of processes that have died get reused, they do not increment monotonically for all time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Linux kernel already maintains a count of the total number of forks in the system as a whole.

One of the tasks performed by [`copy_process()`](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/kernel/fork.c#L964), which does a lot of the work involved in forking, is to [increment the `total_forks` counter](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/kernel/fork.c#L1301).

This counter is exposed to userland as the `processes` line in `/proc/stat` (by the code [here](http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v2.6.32/fs/proc/stat.c#L115)).

Answer (score 1):

The source code for `fork` can be found at `<linux kernel source tree>/kernel/fork.c` file. The function is `do_fork`. You can add your code right before the `else` statement which returns errors. Remember that you would have to compile and reboot with this new kernel.